# transition on transform property in short code

Tags: css, css-transitions, css-transforms

I'm getting confused how to write this code properly ?

option 1:

```css
.line-all {
  -webkit-transition: transform 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.01, 0.165, 0.99);
  transition: transform 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.01, 0.165, 0.99);
}

.animated .line-all {
  -ms-transform: translate(0px, 3px) rotate(-45deg);
  -webkit-transform: translate(0px, 3px) rotate(-45deg);
  transform: translate(0px, 3px) rotate(-45deg);
}
```

Option 2:

```css
.line-all {
  -webkit-transition: transform 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.01, 0.165, 0.99), -webkit-transform 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.01, 0.165, 0.99), -ms-transform 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.01, 0.165, 0.99);
  transition: transform 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.01, 0.165, 0.99), -webkit-transform 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.01, 0.165, 0.99), -ms-transform 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.01, 0.165, 0.99);
}

.animated .line-all {
  -ms-transform: translate(0px, 3px) rotate(-45deg);
  -webkit-transform: translate(0px, 3px) rotate(-45deg);
  transform: translate(0px, 3px) rotate(-45deg);
}
```

Option 3:

```css
.line-all {
  -webkit-transition: transform 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.01, 0.165, 0.99), -webkit-transform 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.01, 0.165, 0.99), -ms-transform 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.01, 0.165, 0.99);
  transition: transform 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.01, 0.165, 0.99);
}

.animated .line-all {
  -ms-transform: translate(0px, 3px) rotate(-45deg);
  -webkit-transform: translate(0px, 3px) rotate(-45deg);
  transform: translate(0px, 3px) rotate(-45deg);
}
```

any other option to write? or which one is right to go from above 3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just got my answer and working well also

```css
.line-all {
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.01, 0.165, 0.99);
  transition: transform 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.01, 0.165, 0.99);
}

.animated .line-all {
  -ms-transform: translate(0px, 3px) rotate(-45deg);
  -webkit-transform: translate(0px, 3px) rotate(-45deg);
  transform: translate(0px, 3px) rotate(-45deg);
}
```